# cocos2d setSourcePosition

Tags: cocos2d-x

What does `setSourcePosition` do for `CCParticleSystemQuad`? I can not find the description anywhere. I guess it is a way of following a sprite? If yes then I add  CCParticleSystemQuad instance as a child to my sprite whom it should follow and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

it sourcePosition of the emitter.

Typically a particle system's position and motion in 3D space are controlled by what is referred to as an emitter. The emitter acts as the source of the particles.

Comment: You can control the source position of the emitter by changing `CCParticleSystemQuad` rotation and also by addChild-ing the `CCParticleSystemQuad` into other sprite and change the position of the sprite, isn't it?